# Equivalence of locally connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is true this equivalence?

$A\subseteq X$ is locally connected in $X$ if and only if for each $U$ open in $X$ such that $x\in U$, exists a open connected set $K$ such that $x\in K \subseteq U$ and $K \cap A$ is connected.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Is obviously, but the converse I can´t. Any hint?, thanks.

Comment: Something's missing. What if $K=\{x\}$?

Comment: $K$ has to be open.

Comment: What does it mean for $A$ to be locally connected **in** $X$? Local connectedness is an absolute property of the space $A$. Perhaps you mean $A \subset X$ is locally connected if and only if ....

Comment: Yes, sorry $K$ is open. Is this case is true?

Comment: Paul Frost $A$ is locally connected which the topology of the subspace inherited for $X$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Rightarrow$ is false. Let $X = \{0\} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{1/n\}$ with the topology inherited from $\mathbb R$. The subspace $A= \{0\}$ is locally connected, but $0$ has **no** open connected neighborhood $K$ in $X$.